# React native background geolocation when app killed

Tags: react-native, background, geolocation

I’m trying to get users location when app is on background.
I managed to do that by installing the npm module “@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation” and my problem is that when I close the app (swipe upwards to close the app) it stops send me the location.
Is it supposed to behave this way? Or I’m using this npm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, please check if user has granted **Always** authorization.

Also, ensure that you have kept **Location updates** in **Background modes** enabled inside Xcode Project -> Target -> Capabilities

From Apple Docs -

> Using Location Services in the Background Most location services are
>   meant to be used while your app is in the foreground but some can also
>   run in the background. In some cases, location events can even cause
>   your app to be relaunched to process an event. To run most location
>   services in the background, you need to enable the location updates
>   background mode in the Capabilities tab of your Xcode project. For
>   services that launch your app, you need to request (and be granted)
>   “Always” authorization from the user.
>
> The standard location service delivers events normally while an app is
>   running in the foreground. When your app is in the background, this
>   service delivers events only when the location-updates background mode
>   is enabled for the app. This service does not relaunch iOS apps that
>   have been terminated.
>
> The significant location change service delivers events normally while
>   an app is running in the foreground or background. For a terminated
>   iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of
>   this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.